# Sourcetree commit description

Tags: git, macos, git-commit, atlassian-sourcetree, git-gui

How can I write a description to my commit message through the client? I’ve been searching around for this but not find anything.

My goal is to have something like:

```
This I my commit message.
And this is the description that explains the message a bit more in case I need it
```

I know you can achieve this via terminal for example.

Thanks!

Comment: You say "the client" but then have two tags that imply two different "client"s: [tag:atlassian-sourcetree] and [tag:git-gui]. Which one(s) do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Simply type your header message, then press space two times and then hit enter two times.
Its just like in markdown:
[image]